# What is the stock warrant's expiration date here?

Tags: trading, online-trading, warrants

https://www.etrade.wallst.com/v1/stocks/snapshot/snapshot.asp?symbol=IPOA.WS

> SOCIAL CAP HEDOSOPHIA HLDGS CO WT EXP 000022 IPOA.WS: NYSE

How do I interpret the expiration date here WT EXP 000022 ? Is it January 1st 2022?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These warrants do not have a fixed expiration date, rather their expiration date is dependant upon the company completing an acquisition.  Thirty days after the acquisition is complete the warrants enter their *exercise period*.  The warrants can then be exercised at any time over the next five years.  After five years they expire.

From the "WARRANT AGREEMENT SOCIAL CAPITAL HEDOSOPHIA HOLDINGS CORP.":

> A Warrant may be exercised only during the period (the “Exercise Period”) (A) commencing on the later of: (i) the date that is thirty (30) days after the first date on which the Company completes a merger, share exchange, asset acquisition, share purchase, reorganization or similar business combination, involving the Company and one or more businesses (a “Business Combination”), and (ii) the date that is twelve (12) months from the date of the closing of the Offering, and (B) terminating at the earliest to occur of (x) 5:00 p.m., New York City time on the date that is five (5) years after the date on which the Company completes its initial Business Combination, (y) the liquidation of the Company in accordance with the Company’s amended and restated memorandum and articles of association, as amended from time to time, if the Company fails to complete a Business Combination, and (z) 5:00 p.m., New York City time on, other than with respect to the Private Placement Warrants, the Redemption Date (as defined below) as provided in Section 6.2 hereof (the “Expiration Date”); provided, however, that the exercise of any Warrant shall be subject to the satisfaction of any applicable conditions, as set forth in subsection 3.3.2 below, with respect to an effective registration statement

Source : [lawinsder.com](https://www.lawinsider.com/contracts/5HBOWpGR5PHYqHb3hoCK2h/social-capital-hedosophia-holdings-corp/1706946/2017-09-18)